# Problem in randomizing the geometry of 'Instances on Points' that is based on another meshes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to create a scene that is having a lot of random meshes run toward the centre.

I randomized the line of meshes sequence, but when i put it on the points of a UV sphere, it doesn't randomize and looks like a pattern. Picture below:[image]

Here's my geometry node map.[image]

I am not really familiar with the geometry node and have been stuck in this issues for a while...

Comment: If I read well (please prefer sharing your file instead of just a screen capture), you're generating a curve with objects in it. But this **same** curve is itself instanciated. So... same pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, as you're distributing object instances into a single curve, the same pattern appears because this same instance is repeated when itself instanciated.

So you can distribute the objects after the curve is instanciated and **realized** so that it is not the same instance anymore.

Something like this:

[image]

---

Note that you could do it another way:

[image]

Extrude sphere vertices.

Keep only the extruded edges by separating them.

Convert to curve and resample in order to have the wanted amount of vertices.

Then instanciate.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!!!:D